# polymer build returns this error

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

I am trying to setup a Polymer Blank application w these instructions
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/install-2-0

1. I am using the latest ver of node, npm and polymer
2. I create a test project (redcloud) and use polymer init w app template
3. polymer server shows blank screen
4. running `polymer build` and also `js compile` option both return the error below...

```
sudo polymer build --js-compile
```

> info:    Clearing build/ directory...
>
> info:    (default) Building...
>
> error:   Uncaught exception: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>
> open '/Users/greg/redcloud/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js'
>
> error:   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/greg/redcloud/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js'

Answer (score 0):

Run `bower install` before trying to build the app. (It seems there are some missing bower dependencies.)

Comment: thank you @nicolas. 
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:18:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.

Comment: hmm maybe restart from scratch - should just work. Also do not use "sudo" to run your commands in general -

Comment: yes I restarted from scratch and incl the latest RC. it seems polymer init pulls the bower stuff needed anyway. one thing I notice with the default PRPL app template is that Service Worker is not running. "Service worker disabled for development, will be generated at build time."